# How to change wordpress Log In text

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I just started learning WordPress and in my current project I want to change WordPress default:

> Log In

Text to:

> Welcom To Monastery

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Glad to hear that you got interested in Wordpress.

[Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) for customizing the **Login Form**:

And because you want to add custom text I would recommend you create a custom Login form.

[Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page) for creating a custom Login form.

Comment: No probs. If you need any help, let me know. If you found my answer helpful please mark it as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
    add_action('login_form', 'wpse17709_login_form');
    function wpse17709_login_form()
    {
      add_filter('gettext', 'wpse17709_gettext', 10, 2);
    }

    function wpse17709_gettext($translation, $text)
    {
      if ('Log In' == $text) {
        return 'Welcom To Monastery';
      }
      return $translation;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function my_login_logo_url_title() {
   return 'Welcom To Monastery';}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

Change login name threw apply this code in functions.php in your wordpress.

Comment: Please don't just add CODE as an answer, add some text to explain what the CODE does. This way it's easier for the beginners to understand what it's for and also the post can be easily found from searching.

Comment: Sorry for that i am new at stackoverflow.com that's why i will be careful for next posts

Comment: That's OK, we all start from somewhere. What's important is that we learn in the process. Welcome to WPSE.